# generate class name?

Tags: php

how can you do something like this?

```
require_once 'class.Table_'.$table.'.php';
$class = new Table_$table();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$className = $var.'someString'.$var2;

$obj = new $className();
```

In your case

```
$className = 'Table_'.$table;

$obj = new $className();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Pretty much the way you did it.](http://codepad.org/eUyuLl0Y)

The variable has to be the whole class name.

So:

```
<?php
$clsName = "Table_a";

require_once "class.{$clsName}.php";
$class = new $clsName();
?>
```

This is [supported since PHP 5.2](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).